# SSRS 2012 Always prompt for login

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am using SSRS 2012 for Reporting and when i deploy it on production server and try to access the report then it always prompt me for login and if we put the server login details then its working fine.

I want to avoid this login prompt and How can i do this, i did many search on Google and try do implement these but not get any luck.

Please help us.

Thanks
Atul

Comment: Are you connecting with Internet Explorer or another browser? If IE, what zone does it say the report server is in?

Comment: It is prompting for every browser..

Answer (score 0):

Check the IE's 'User authentication' settings (refer to screenshot in
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/axinthefield/archive/2011/05/06/logon-dialog-box-when-launching-a-reporting-services-report-from-ax.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Hope your issue is solved now. But I was looking to overcome same problem, and as I got a solution. I thought some other people might get help from this.

I was trying to deploy a report to our production server but it would prompt for user credentials again and again but wont deploy the report, and everything seemed to be alright with the report.

I tried every credentials being used on the server but nothing worked.

Eventually I had a thought that there are **.RDL, .RDS** files being used to generate report and somehow the same should be uploaded on the server and this time I used the FTP User account credentials and Bingo!, it worked.

Hope this saves time of other people.

Answer (score 0):

IE Settings:

1. Open Internet Explorer
2. Go to Tools and click on Internet Options
3. Under the Security tab, click on Trusted sites and click the Sites button and Add Report Manager/Report Server URL to the trusted
   sites.
4. Then click Custom Level, and check the option Automatic logon with current user name and password
5. Repeat #3 and #4 for Local Intranet

Taken from: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b1efd3f0-4fc5-4015-b13a-b79737466271/how-to-stop-prompting-for-username-password-when-i-click-report-server-web-service-urls-in-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices

Answer (score -1):

Login into "Server"/ReportServer

- Click on rdl file "drop down"
- Select Manage
- check if the Data Source's Connection String box is empty

  - If it's empty, provide the Connection String again
- Select the Option Windows Integrated Security
- Test and save your Connection String.

This will overwrite your localhost credentials.